# Analytic Report Chart not working in iframe

Tags: visualforce, analytics, iframe, reports-api, report-chart

What I am trying to do is to land on the actual report after clicking on chart which is rendered on VF page using Iframe.
First I have used `<analytics:reportChart>` tag on the VF page to see the Report Chart based on the [suggestion](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005WtJQAU) but somehow, it was not working hence went for the option of using [iFrame](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AbKNIA0)

But now when I click on that chart it gives error.

Embedded VF Page in Iframe:
[image]

zChartPOC Page:
[image]

Report Chart showing as below:
[image]

When I click on any report, it shows below error:
[image]

Can you please help and let me know how can we achieve this?

Comment: Have you enabled ClickJack protection? `Setup->Security Controls->Session Setting`

Comment: I don't want to enable ClickJack as it may affect other things, hence is there any other way to move forward on this, is there any way to get report chart out of Iframe?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a case that ClickJack protections are enabled in your org. Follow this path:

> Setup->Security Controls->Session Setting

You need to raise a case with Salesforce to disable it.